# how to write a modal popup in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, popup

I have a table that displays data along side with a button, I want the button to display a modal popup when it's click. I have written a javascript code to do that but it's not working. I don't have much knowledge about JavaScript. The Edit button is not displaying the popup modal when it's clicked. I don't really know if the error is from the javascript file or the html page.

```
        Here is the Javascript file that I named country.js
        
        
        $('document').ready(function(){
            $('table #editButton').on('click',function(event){
                $('#editModal').modal();
            });
        });
        
        Here is the html where the data is displayed.
        
        <section class="section dashboard">
            <div class="row">
        
              <!-- Left side columns -->
        
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
        
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                  <!-- Image background -->
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Add A Country</button>
                   <h1>List of Country</h1>
                      <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Code</th>
                          <th>Capital</th>
                          <th>Description</th>
                          <th>Nationality</th>
                          <th>Continent</th>
                          <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="country:${countries}">
                          <td th:text="${country.getId}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${country.getCode}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${country.getCapital}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${country.getDescription}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${country.getNationality}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${country.getContinent}"></td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" id="editButton">Edit</a>                  
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
        
                    </div><!-- End of Image background -->
            </div><!-- End Left side columns -->
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        
        And this is the modal popup in the html page and I have also called the javascript file in this html page but I don't know why the popup is not displaying
        
        <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Update Country</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form th:action="@{/countries/addNew}" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="codeEdit" class="col-form-label">Code:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codeEdit" name="code">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="capitalEdit" class="col-form-label">Capital:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="capitalEdit" name="capital">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="descriptionEdit" class="col-form-label">Description:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descriptionEdit" name="description">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nationalityEdit" class="col-form-label">Nationality:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nationalityEdit" name="nationality">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="continentEdit" class="col-form-label">Continent:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="continentEdit" name="continent">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
        <script src="assets/vendor/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/vendor/chart.js/chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/vendor/echarts/echarts.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/vendor/quill/quill.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/vendor/simple-datatables/simple-datatables.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/vendor/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Template Main JS File -->
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/country.js"></script>
        </body>
```

Comment: You can't create a real modal pop-up with JS.

Comment: I'll contradict Teemu and say you _can_ do what is commonly referred to as a modal in front end dev though :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example code isn't just regular JavaScript, it looks like jQuery and it looks like you are trying to use a jQuery modal plugin. If that's the route you want to go, you need to do some setup that depends on your specific situation. Your code and setup is so complex and specific that I recommend learning more fundamentals before proceeding OR rebuilding this specific part of your application.

Also; you are using IDs to target your elements, but you have multiple elements with the same ID, which should never happen.

Below I have a tiny demo of a custom "modal" type thing using just HTML, CSS and vanilla (meaning plain) JS without jQuery

```js
function toggleModal(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    backdrop.classList.toggle("active")
}
const backdrop = document.querySelector(".backdrop")
const button = document.querySelector("button")
backdrop.addEventListener("click", toggleModal)
button.addEventListener("click", toggleModal)
```

```css
.backdrop {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  cursor:pointer;
  background:#00000088;
  top: 0;
}
.backdrop.active {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.modal {
  background: #ffffff;
  min-width:30vw;
  min-height: 30vh;
  cursor:initial;
}
```

```html
<button>OpenModal</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel consectetur ex, id pharetra ex. In ligula leo, euismod eu gravida sed, facilisis non dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean sapien dolor, aliquam quis odio a, feugiat rutrum turpis. Duis eu eleifend urna. Fusce quis quam hendrerit, varius nibh sed, tempor erat. Fusce iaculis finibus lacus in fringilla. Nullam tincidunt odio eu efficitur lacinia. Vivamus id tempus mauris, in laoreet magna. Integer ornare, odio quis ullamcorper ultrices, purus nisl elementum erat, id semper eros nunc et orci. Morbi neque purus, fringilla ut rutrum quis, commodo vel arcu.</p>
<p>Integer sit amet volutpat ante. Donec sed sem non nisi hendrerit volutpat ac vel ante. Suspendisse nec nulla interdum, aliquam mauris non, porta elit. Suspendisse potenti. Proin placerat tincidunt malesuada. Nullam accumsan mi finibus orci pretium pharetra. Nunc at efficitur leo, sit amet ultrices arcu. Aenean non nibh congue, efficitur justo et, posuere ante. Phasellus maximus augue at pulvinar pulvinar. Integer tempor, orci eu pellentesque finibus, enim tortor hendrerit dui, quis semper lorem dolor ac nulla. Mauris congue venenatis blandit. Pellentesque a mi in odio venenatis iaculis vel non elit.</p>

<div class="backdrop">
  <div class="modal">
    I am a modal
  </div>
</div>
```